# Alternatives to Redis with support for set structures?

Tags: database, redis, nosql

Are there databases other than Redis that support [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)?oldformat=true) structures out of the box? I surprisingly could not find any in my searches, but I suspect that Redis must not be alone in supporting this type of data set.

Comment: Cassandra: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_set_t.html